# Epcot World Reorder

Tags: code-golf, sorting

## Intoroduction

If you've ever been to [Epcot](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Epcot_map.png) at Disney World, you've probably been to the world showcase: a lake surrounded by various country-themed locations. One thing that's always bothered me about it is that the countries don't appear in the order you would run into them around the world. There are officially eleven of them, and the order is (going clockwise around the circle):

```
Mexico
Norway
China
Germany
Italy
United States
Japan
Morocco
France
United Kingdom
Canada
```

## Challenge

Write a function or program that takes the list of countries (as a list, separated string, or other convenient form) in the order given above, and return/output them in an order that you would run into them if you were head around the world (either east-west or west-east) from a start point of your choosing. For specificity, lets define the capital of each country as it's "position", and order [longitudinally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude). Output format should be the same as the input format.

Standard code golf rules apply. Shortest code wins, with exception to the bonus below. The winner will be determined by the code with the lowest score that accomplishes the criteria, and will be selected in a minimum of seven days.

## Bonus

If your code can take in arbitrary country names (beyond just the eleven listed above) and order them as well, subtract 33% from your score. If you invoke this bonus, you must start from the [Prime Meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian), but which direction you go from there is up to you. Because the total number of "[sovereign states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sovereign_state)" is a disputed thing, I'll settle for at least 190 of them.

## Example

### Input

```
['Mexico', 'Norway', 'China', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'Unites States', 'Japan', 'Morocco', 'France', 'United Kingdom', 'Canada']
```

### Output

```
['Mexico', 'United States', 'Canada', 'Morocco', 'United Kingdom','France', 'Norway', 'Italy', 'Germany', 'China', 'Japan']
```

Comment: If you can only go east or west, and only the longitude of the capital counts, then the output can only be a reversed/rotated version of the example output, correct?

Comment: @Calvin'sHobbies That is correct, unless you're going for the bonus, which limits it further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### CJam (18 bytes)

This is an anonymous function which takes input as an array of strings and returns it as an array of strings.

```
{36061983185Bb\f=}
```

[Online demo](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~%0A%0A%7B36061983185Bb%5Cf%3D%7D%0A%0A~%60&input=%5B%22Mexico%22%20%22Norway%22%20%22China%22%20%22Germany%22%20%22Italy%22%20%22United%20States%22%20%22Japan%22%20%22Morocco%22%20%22France%22%20%22United%20Kingdom%22%20%22Canada%22%5D)

A slightly more general version, which takes any subset of the 11 countries in any order and sorts them correctly, is 26 bytes:

```
{{71b226%75585218525Bb=}$}
```

For the 30% bonus to give a better score, it would be necessary to encode the data for 190 countries in at most 37 bytes (including the code to use it); that's about 1.5 bits per country. But 190! is about 2^1169.3, requiring 147 bytes, so the 30% bonus is obviously not at all interesting without cheating by using external data sources.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't want to make the bonus too high, because I figured then something like mathmatica would just win outright. But I wanted the possible incentive for people to write the harder program at the very least for the challenge of it. Nice work.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica, 50 bytes

```
f=SortBy[CountryData[#,"CapitalLocation"][[1,2]]&]
```

Example:

```
In[12]:= f@{"Mexico", "Norway", "China", "Germany", "Italy", 
  "United States", "Japan", "Morocco", "France", "United Kingdom", 
  "Canada"}

Out[12]= {Mexico,United States,Canada,Morocco,United Kingdom,France,Norway,Italy,Germany,China,Japan}
```

Mathematica has built-in functions for every kind of data like this...

---

With bonus:

## Mathematica, 58 bytes − 33% = 38.86 bytes

```
f=SortBy[CountryData[#,"CapitalLocation"][[1,2]]~Mod~360&]
```

Comment: I had a feeling Mathematica would have something for this, but wasn't sure how concise it would be. Well done!